# changing order of layers in legend interface " QGIS 2.6" as using layerTreeCanvasBridge() gives attribute error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.6

Want to bring the active layer to top of the legend interface layer list.

Comment: I don't have groups(layers are not grouped) and the above code is not working for me

Comment: @drama - Can you specify whether you want the order changed in the _Layers Panel_ or the _Layer Order Panel_?

Comment: layers panel  actually

Comment: @drama - Can you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/243606/edit) your question to include the code you used? The answer to the link in my previous comment should work :)

Comment: ya sure here it is,    
            iface1.setActiveLayer(layer)
            iface1.legendInterface().moveLayer(layer, 0)

Comment: @drama - Did you try using the code in this answer?: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/how-to-move-layers-in-the-qgis-table-of-contents-via-pyqgis/134305#134305](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/how-to-move-layers-in-the-qgis-table-of-contents-via-pyqgis/134305#134305)

Comment: I haven't actually coz I dont have any root layer.....     should i try then too

Comment: @drama - Try replacing `alayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("Layer2")[0]` with `alayer = iface.activeLayer()` then use the code to move `alayer`. "root" is not a layer, it's the name given to the layers panel essentially.

Comment: This one  worked                                                    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/how-to-move-l‌​ayers-in-the-qgis-ta‌​ble-of-contents-via-‌​pyqgis/134305#134305

Comment: Most welcome, glad you got it to work! Yes, I think the wrong question has been chosen for a duplicate. Will flag this and ask a moderator to change it :)

Comment: ya because,                                                                                                           AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'layerTreeCanvasBridge'                                                                                   QGIS 2.6 gives error !

Comment: actually ,                                                                                                               How to move layers in the QGIS Table of Contents via PyQGIS?   has worked

Comment: question is duplicate srry