# How to synchronize layer orders in QGIS "layers()" and in the Layers Panels GUI

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to change the order of layers in qgis3 (python). But the code I can come up with **only** changes the order of layers in the list `iface.mapCanvas().layers()`, and not the displayed layer order in the lower left `Layers Panel` in the GUI.

My code below, e.g. swaps the orders of two arbitrary loaded layers. The `print()` statement shows that orders in `layers()` are indeed swapped with each run of the code.

```
lyr1 = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
lyr2 = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1]
treeRoot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
treeRoot.setHasCustomLayerOrder(True)
order = treeRoot.customLayerOrder()
order.append(order.pop(0))
treeRoot.setCustomLayerOrder( order )
iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().setCanvasLayers()

print (iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0].name())
print (iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1].name())
```

I expected this to change the layer orders in QGIS GUI as well. However, the `Layers Panel` stays the same after running the scripts multiple times.

How can I synchronize the `Layers Panel` to reflect the order changes in the underlying `layers()`?

Comment: As far as I understand, you're setting the layer order in Layer Order Panel (see  https://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge.html#aa1da33b746370800346232bd89dba1e4) and not in the Layers Panel. From the docs, "This is useful in advanced cases where the grouping in layer tree should be independent from the actual order in the canvas." See this question for more context: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229587/how-to-move-layers-in-the-layer-order-panel-using-pyqgis/229646#229646

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Thanks. Do you know how to change the layer order in non-"advanced" cases:) I searched quite a bit and couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you see this already? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/moving-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents-via-pyqgis/134305#134305