# Selecting the active layer in Layers tree in QGIS

Tags: qgis, table-of-contents

How do I programmatically (in QGIS with Python) set the position of the active layer and show it in the legend tree. 
Specifically if the layer is in a collapsed group or is it far below the list?

Comment: I tried to run in the console

`iface.setActiveLayer(iface.activeLayer ())
iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(iface.activeLayer())
iface.legendInterface().setCurrentLayer(iface.activeLayer())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving layers in QGIS Table of Contents via PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/moving-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents-via-pyqgis)

Comment: Problem solved:  
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()  
    view = self.iface.layerTreeView()  
    view.setCurrentLayer(None)  
    view.setCurrentLayer(layer)